# Can't end while loop (C++)

Tags: c++, while-loop

I can't seem to end this while loop and I have tried every single way I know but it's still not working. The variable "contGame" just kept changing to "true" even if I have already changed it to "false". Can you guys help me! Note that this inside a class. Here is my code:

```
while (contGame == true)
    {
        if (turn == 1)
        {
            cout << Board._player1Name <<"'s turn!!\n";
            X = getMoveX();
            Y = getMoveY();

            Board.Board[X][Y] = player1Sign;
            Board.printBoard();
            turn = turn + 1;
            Board.checkGame(contGame, player1Sign, player2Sign);
            if (checkGame(contGame, player1Sign, player2Sign) == false)
            {
                bool contGame = false;
                cout << contGame << endl;
            }
        } 
        cout << contGame << endl;
        if(turn == 2)
        {
            cout << Board._player2Name <<"'s turn!!\n";
            X = getMoveX();
            Y = getMoveY();

            Board.Board[X][Y] = player2Sign;
            Board.printBoard();
            turn = turn - 1;
            Board.checkGame(contGame, player1Sign, player2Sign);
            if (checkGame(contGame, player1Sign, player2Sign) == false)
            {
                int contGame = 1;
                cout << contGame << endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is checkGame:

```
bool contGameA = true;
for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {

        if (Board[k][0] == Board[k][1] && Board[k][1] == Board[k][2] && Board[k][2] == player1Sign)
        {
            cout << "\\\\" << _player1Name <<" wins!////\n";
            contGameA = false;
        }
        else if (Board[k][0] == Board[k][1] && Board[k][1] == Board[k][2] && Board[k][2] == player2Sign)
        {
            cout << "\\\\" << _player2Name << " wins!////\n";
            contGameA = false;
        }
    }

for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++)
    {
        if (Board[0][r] == Board[1][r] && Board[1][r] == Board[2][r] && Board[2][r] == player1Sign)
        {
            cout << "\\\\" << _player1Name << " wins!////\n";
            contGameA = false;
        }
        else if (Board[0][r] == Board[1][r] && Board[1][r] == Board[2][r] && Board[2][r] == player2Sign)
        {
            cout << "\\\\" << _player2Name << " wins!////\n";
            contGameA = false;
        }   
    }

if (Board[0][0] == Board[1][1] && Board[1][1] == Board[2][2] && Board[2][2] == player1Sign)
    {
        cout << "\\\\" << _player1Name << " wins!////\n";
        contGameA = false;
    } else if (Board[0][0] == Board[1][1] && Board[1][1] == Board[2][2] && Board[2][2] == player2Sign)
    {
        cout << "\\\\" << _player2Name << " wins!////\n";
        contGameA = false;
    }

if (Board[0][2] == Board[1][1] && Board[1][1] == Board[2][0] && Board[2][0] == player1Sign)
    {
        cout << "\\\\" << _player1Name << " wins!////\n";
        contGameA = false;
    } else if (Board[0][2] == Board[1][1] && Board[1][1] == Board[2][0] && Board[2][0] == player2Sign)
    {
        cout << "\\\\" << _player2Name << " wins!////\n";
        contGameA = false;
    }
return contGameA;
```

Comment: While I did answer the question because I happened to spot the error in the wall of code you posted, please note that your question is far from providing a [mcve], because of the "minimal" part. Before posting, you should shorten the code as much as possible (while keeping it reproducing the error, of course).

Answer (score 2):

You are actually creating `contGame` variable in the nested scope of your `if` statement and this is hiding `contGame` variable declared in the outer scope.
As a result you never change the outer `contGame` variable

e.g.

```
if (checkGame(contGame, player1Sign, player2Sign) == false)
{
    // bool contGame = false; should be:
    contGame = false;
    cout << contGame << endl;
}
```

and

```
if (checkGame(contGame, player1Sign, player2Sign) == false)
{
    // int contGame = 1; should be
    contGame = true;
    cout << contGame << endl;
}
```

Comment: I removed  "bool" and "int" but the loop still wouldn't end. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You keep declaring new variables with the name `contGame` in nested scopes, and modifying those. These are entirely separate variables, which (in their scope) *hide* the outer variable `contGame`. It's that *outer one* on whose value the `while` loop depends.

Remove the `bool` and `int` from the lines:

```
bool contGame = false;

// and

int contGame = 1;
```

to have these lines affect the outer `contGame` variable. Also note that `1` is converted to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the variables only falls within the brackets when declared inside a any loop.
Remove the `bool` and `int` and just put

```
if (checkGame(contGame, player1Sign, player2Sign) == false)
{
contGame = false;
}
```